# Set Couchbase client bucket password in C# code

Tags: c#, couchbase

In my C# code, I want to create a Couchbase client using the ctor version that I can pass in the bucketName and password:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Initializes a new instance of the Couchbase.CouchbaseClient class using the
//     default configuration and the specified bucket.
//
// Remarks:
//     The configuration is taken from the /configuration/Couchbase section.
public CouchbaseClient(string bucketName, string bucketPassword);
```

In my web.config file the `<couchbase>` section looks like this:

```
<couchbase>
  <servers bucket="beer-sample" bucketPassword="">
    <add uri="localhost:8091/pools" />
  </servers>
</couchbase>
```

And in the code I try to create a Couchbase client by:

```
var cc = new CouchbaseClient("beer-sample", "ThePassword");
```

The above line always failing with error "cannot locate note". Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using an old version of the Couchbase .Net SDK.
CouchbaseClient is the old way of using Couchbase.

Please refer to the new Guide -> http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dotnet-2.1/dotnet-intro.html

Second, you must have your bucket created with the password you want to have.

for example:

```
    var clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfiguration.Servers = new List<Uri> { new Uri("http://localhost:8091") };

    Cluster Cluster = new Cluster(clientConfiguration);
    using (var bucket = Cluster.OpenBucket("bucketpwd", "1234"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bucket Opened");
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit old topic  but maybe it could help people with the same issue.

I'm currently using couchbase .net client 2.7.5

```
var clusterConfig = new ClientConfiguration
{
    Servers = new List<Uri>{new Uri("http://couchbase0-node.io:8091")},
    PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration()
};

using (var cluster = new Cluster(clusterConfig))
{
    var authenticator = new PasswordAuthenticator(username, password);
    cluster.Authenticate(authenticator);
    using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket(bucketName))
    {
        // Do something like :
        var data = await bucket.GetAsync<T>(cacheKey);
        // Other staff
    }
}
```

See more on : https://docs.couchbase.com/dotnet-sdk/2.7/start-using-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer this document for Couchbase Server 3.0/3.1

```
    ClientConfiguration example

var config = new ClientConfiguration
{
  Servers = new List<Uri>
  {
    new Uri("http://192.168.56.101:8091/pools"),
    new Uri("http://192.168.56.102:8091/pools"),
    new Uri("http://192.168.56.103:8091/pools"),
    new Uri("http://192.168.56.104:8091/pools"),
  },
  UseSsl = true,
  DefaultOperationLifespan = 1000,
  BucketConfigs = new Dictionary<string, BucketConfiguration>
  {
    {"default", new BucketConfiguration
    {
      BucketName = "default",
      UseSsl = false,
      Password = "",
      DefaultOperationLifespan = 2000,
      PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration
      {
        MaxSize = 10,
        MinSize = 5,
        SendTimeout = 12000
      }
    }}
  }
};

using (var cluster = new Cluster(config))
{
  IBucket bucket = null;
  try
  {
    bucket = cluster.OpenBucket();
    //use the bucket here
  }
  finally
  {
    if (bucket != null)
    {
      cluster.CloseBucket(bucket);
    }
   }
  }
}
```

http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dotnet-2.1/configuring-the-client.html